# loading google maps drawing manager object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So i am using Google Maps Drawing Manager to draw some polygons and i am saving the lat e long coordinates to my database. Now my question is, after i load that to my array, how can i rebuild the saved polygon back into my map? I can't seem to find a code to understand that.

this is what i have now :

```
    window.initialize_2 = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = maplimits;

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
        },
        markerOptions: {
            icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#ffff00',
            fillOpacity: 10,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: true,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
 });

    var coord_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
        console.log(coordinates);
        window.poly = polygon;
    });

    //delete shape
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
                setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
        }
    });

    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);

    drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the polygon should stay on your map. I am guessing you mean at some later time in another instance of the map you want to draw the polygon based on earlier input? In that case you would create a [Polygon Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons). It's pretty straightforward in the documentation I just linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Set a global array (it's easier) and, at the listener, store the polygon on it, then make a function to set it to the map.

Something like this:

```
var polygons = [];

window.initialize_2 = function () {
var mapOptions = {
...
var coord_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
        console.log(coordinates);
        window.poly = polygon;
        poligons = [] // clear the array
        polygons.push(polygon); // insert the polygon into the array
    });
...
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
}

function setPolygon(){
  polygons[0].setMap(map) // set the polygon to the map
}
```

Hope it help you a little.
Regards.